# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java320 in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I have an Eclipse to built open CV-3.2.0 Java project. I can add open CV jar files in Eclipse. I create first small program on Java and I got error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java320 in java.library.path.

I worked on Ubuntu.

**My code looks like:**

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat mat=Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println(mat.dump());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added your openCV jar to your project path?

Comment: I already add a jar file.

Comment: I face this issue too